# Como criar marcador no logback?

Tags: java, log, logback

Estou tentando criar um marcador dentro do meu appender do logback e não consegui. Meu código é

```
  <appender name="ErrorFile" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
    <!-- Support multiple-JVM writing to the same log file -->
    <evaluator class="ch.qos.logback.classic.boolex.OnMarkerEvaluator">
        <marker>NOTIFY_ERROR</marker>
    </evaluator>
    <prudent>true</prudent>
    <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
        <fileNamePattern>mensageiroErro.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
        <maxHistory>30</maxHistory> 
    </rollingPolicy>

    <encoder>
        <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} ${LOG_LEVEL_PATTERN:-%5p} ${PID:- } - [%t] %-40.40logger{39} : [%X{MDC_TOKEN}%X{camel.breadcrumbId}] %m%n${LOG_EXCEPTION_CONVERSION_WORD:-%wEx}</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Na hora de subir a aplicação dá o seguinte erro:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected: 
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@21:76 - no applicable action for [evaluator], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][evaluator]]
ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.spi.Interpreter@22:21 - no applicable action for [marker], current ElementPath  is [[configuration][appender][evaluator][marker]]
```

Provavelmente é porque está no lugar errado. Mas eu fiz de acordo com a documentação de appenders do logback:

```
http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html
```

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que o seu appender não suporta notificações.

Veja que no [exemplo](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#OnMarkerEvaluator), ele usa `ch.qos.logback.classic.net.SMTPAppender`, que possui implementações especiais para enviar uma mensagem de notificação.